# How use Inner Join with a computed column in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, fluent

I recently discovered the computed column value in EF Core:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
.Property(p => p.DisplayName)
.HasComputedColumnSql("[LastName] + ', ' + [FirstName]");
```

How would you do an inner join to another table with this same approach?

Comment: I wouldn't use joins at all. It's EF Core's job to generate JOINs based on the relations between entities. If you have to use JOINs in your queries, the model is missing relations

Comment: I am using the inheritance feature.  I am then using an override on a virtual property.  In my case, these are different types of scheduled events that I want to store in the same table and differentiate using the discriminator.  A join should be the better performant option compared to injecting the DbContext into the actual class.

Comment: That doesn't mean you have to explicitly join in queries. If you specify the relations, EF Core will create the joins when needed. If you join on computed columns, or specify relations based on them, you'll get the worst possible performance though, unless you use persisted *and* indexed computed columns.

Comment: so say I have Project.Customer.  How can I get the customer name as a computed property?

Comment: Please explain for which purpose do you need that. Looks like you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv

I'm wrote a scheduling a system for my company awhile back.  At that time, there was only one kind of scheduled event.  Now there are many schedule events that have some properties in common, and others that don't.

Using EF core inheritance I've created a base class called ScheduleEvent.  Other classes that are related to scheduling inherit from this class.

Now, I want to be able to request just the base class, but get a description of classes that inherit the base class by using a virtual property on the base class that override the property

Comment: The main reason I'm trying to this, is I can't use .Include on the base class.  I want to request many types with out explicitly using the .Include syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know better solution right now, but adding computation columns to database is worst idea.

What we can do here is just define common method for enriching `ScheduleEvent` with `DisplayName` or other needed properties:

```cs
public class SchedulerEventWithDisplayName
{
    public ScheduleEvent Event { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

Sample of enricher:

```cs
public static IQueryable<SchedulerEventWithDisplayName> EnrichWithDisplayName(IQueryable<ScheduleEvent> source)
{
    return source.Select(e => new SchedulerEventWithDisplayName
    {
        Event = e,
        DisplayName = e is ScheduleEvent1 ? ((ScheduleEvent1)e).Field1 + ((ScheduleEvent1)e).Field2 : 
                      e is ScheduleEvent2 ? ((ScheduleEvent2)e).NavigationProp.Value :
                      "Some Default Value";
    });
}
```

If it will work for you, you can think how to create such enricher dynamically.